# Is there a reason why my buttons aren't working towards my code?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class, mouse-cursor

For my buttons towards my code, it's not allowing the button to turn the cursor into a pointer when moving onto the button, and after a while my hover pseudo class selector is no longer working for the button. I used ChatGPT to figure out where I may have gone wrong, and it showed that putting the buttons in position relative may have screwed the accessibility of the button.

Can you show me where I may have gone wrong with this code?

```css
.hero-btn {
  /*
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left: 30px; */
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-family: 'Open-Sans', sans-serif;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.blog-btn {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.blog-btn:hover {
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
  color: #fff;
}

.sub-btn {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.sub-btn:hover {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" value="Read The Blog" class="blog-btn hero-btn">
          Read The Blog
        </button>
<button type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="sub-btn hero-btn">
          Subscribe
        </button>
```

The input element was used first before being changed over to the button element. The button was once hovering and the cursor: pointer; worked towards the checking the accessibility. After a while the button began to not work when trying to check for accessibility, I tried changing over the class attributes, was a bust there. I tried changing the position or commenting out the position all together still not working. I also redid the code once more to make sure it wasn't a spelling error towards the code.

Comment: Other than the (inaccessible) white on white colour-scheme of the hovered-`<button>` elements, I'm not seeing a problem in your posted code.

Comment: I have the var colors in the root selector for the color scheme and that's the weirdest thing, thats why im wondering how it is not working on the repo, but when it is declared on codepen it works. I am not sure where i may be going wrong.

Comment: The code given works fine. Have you used your browser dev tools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied?

Comment: Yes, and its showing that it is applied in the code but when hovering over it, the color doesn't change nor does the cursor point [link] (https://github.com/KeshonsWalksOfLife/free-thinking-design-Pro.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `yoga-section` element overlaying the buttons, so that when you attempt to click the buttons, you are actually clicking the hitbox of the `yoga-section` element.

The simplest fix is to apply a positive `z-index` to the buttons such that they are stacked on top of the `yoga-section` element:

```css
* { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
} 

:root {
    --primary-color: #33a112;
    --secondary-color:  #3acabb;
    --complementary-color: #fff;
}

body { 
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--complementary-color);
} 

.header { 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    padding: 20px 100px;
    background-color: white; 
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: space-between; 
    align-items: center; 
    z-index: 100; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px; 

}

.logo { 
    font-size: 2rem; 
    color: var(--secondary-color);
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-weight: 600; 
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
} 

.nav-link a { 
    position: relative; 
    font-size: 16px; 
    color: #000; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-weight: 250px; 
    margin-left: 15px; 
    font-family: 'Open-Sans', sans-serif;
} 

.nav-link a::before { 
    content: ''; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%;
    left: 0; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 2px; 
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    transition: .3s;
 }

 .nav-link a:hover { 
    color: var(--secondary-color); 
 }

 .nav-link a:hover::before { 
    width: 100%;
 } 
 
 main#main-header { 
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: -775px;
    padding: 10px 100px;
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: beige;
 } 

div.hero {
    margin-left: 60px;
}

 .hero h1 { 
    font-size: 9rem; 
    color: var(--secondary-color); 
    font-weight: 600; 
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif; 
 }

 .hero h3 { 
    font-size: 1.5rem; 
    color: var(--primary-color); 
    font-weight: 600; 
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif; 
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-left: 30px;
 }

 .hero-h1, .hero-h3 { 
    position: relative;
    top: 120px;
    left: -80px;
    text-align: justify;
 }

img.hero-img { 
    width: 600px; 
    height: 100%; 
    object-fit: cover; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
    margin-left: 215px; 
} 

.hero-disc {
    position: absolute;
    top: 735px;
    left: 110px;
    font-family: 'Open-Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.food1 {
    width: 520px;
    position: relative;
    top: -530px;
    left: 700px;
    z-index: 3;
}

.travel2 {
    width: 550px;
    position: relative;
    top: -540px;
    left: 1110px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.yoga1 {
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    top: -910px;
    left: 549px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.hero-btn {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 200px;
    left: 30px; 
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-family: 'Open-Sans', sans-serif;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.blog-btn {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

.blog-btn:hover {
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    color: #fff;
}

.sub-btn {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

.sub-btn:hover {
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    color: #fff;
}

hr {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

section.yoga-section {
    height: 1275px;
    margin-top: -2px ;
    padding: 10px 100px 10px;
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;  
    border: #000 solid 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

div.yoga-container {
    position: relative;
    top: -600px;
    left: -40px;
}

.yoga-img {
    width: 1300px;
    position: relative;
    top: 650px;
    left: -300px;
}

.h2-1 {
    font-size: 6rem;
    color: var(--complementary-color);
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    top: -235px;
}

.h2-1 span{
    color: var(--primary-color);
    font-size: 8rem;
}

span.peace {
    color: beige;
    font-size: 8rem;
}

section#travel-section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 85vh;
    margin-top: -100px;
    background: linear-gradient(80deg, var(--primary-color), beige);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: gradient 8s ease-in-out infinite;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 50px;
}

@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }

    50% {
        background-position: 100% 65%;
    }
}

article.travel-art-label {
    height: 560px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 180px;
    left: 210px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 25px 25px 20px 0;
    background-color: beige;
}

.flex {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center; 
}

.h2-trav {
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-left: 6px;
} 

h2.places {
    margin-right: 125px;
}

ul li {
    width: 75%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 25px 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: 'Open-Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.travel-with, .travel-way {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 22.5px;
}

.travel-need, .travel-supply {
    margin-top: 47.5px;
}

.list {
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}

li.travel-list {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
}

.list-p {
    font-size:  16px;
    font-style: italic;
}

section#healthy-recipes {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
}

table {
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 2%;
}

h2#healthy-h2 {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    left: 10px
}

.table-head, .table-data {
    border:  2px solid #0a0a23;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.table-head {
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 black;
}

h3#healthy-h3 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-right:  100px;
    margin-top: -250px;
    font-family: 'open-sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
 footer {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      margin-top: -100px;
 }
    
ol.list {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta description="design" />
    <title>Sarah's Blog</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Ubuntu:wght@700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Begin Navigation-->
    <header class="header">
      <div class="nav-logo">
        <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
      </div>

      <div class="nav-link">
        <a href="#home" class="primary">Home</a>
        <a href="#yoga" class="secondary">Yoga</a>
        <a href="#travel" class="primary">Travel</a>
        <a href="#healthy" class="secondary">Healthy Recipes</a>
        <a href="#contact" class="primary">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </header>
    <!--End Navigation-->

    <!--Begin Main-->
    <main id="main-header">
      <div class="hero">
        <h1 class="hero-h1">
          Travel,<br />
          Thrive,<br />
          Transform.
        </h1>
        <h3 class="hero-h3">
          Experience the World through Travel,<br />
          Embrace Wellness with Yoga,<br />
          Discover Health with Wholesome Recipes.
        </h3>
        <p class="hero-disc">
          Join our global community in uncovering a path to personal growth as
          <br />
          we embark on a journey to live a life of meaning and purpose together!
        </p>
        <button type="submit" value="Read The Blog" class="blog-btn hero-btn">
          Read The Blog
        </button>
        <button type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="sub-btn hero-btn">
          Subscribe
        </button>
      </div>
      <!--Begin Hero Images-->
      <div class="img-section">
        <img
          src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/KeshonsWalksOfLife/free-thinking-design-Pro.2/0fd535754c1d4f6f07fdf095defc6a4c5a1a78bc/media/food1.jpg"
          width="25%"
          title="Healthy Food Lifestyle"
          class="hero-img food1"
        />

        <img
          src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/KeshonsWalksOfLife/free-thinking-design-Pro.2/0fd535754c1d4f6f07fdf095defc6a4c5a1a78bc/media/travel2.jpg"
          width="25%"
          title="Traveling Lifestyle"
          class="hero-img travel2"
        />

        <img
          src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/KeshonsWalksOfLife/free-thinking-design-Pro.2/0fd535754c1d4f6f07fdf095defc6a4c5a1a78bc/media/yoga1.jpg"
          width="25%"
          title="Yoga Lifestyle"
          class="hero-img yoga1"
        />
      </div>
    </main>
    <!--End Hero Images-->
    <hr />
    <!--Begin Yoga Section -->
    <section class="yoga-section">
      <div class="yoga-container">
        <img src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/KeshonsWalksOfLife/free-thinking-design-Pro.2/0fd535754c1d4f6f07fdf095defc6a4c5a1a78bc/media/yoga-2.jpg" title="Yoga Lifestyle" class="yoga-img" />
        <h2 class="h2-1">
          Where<br />
          The union of <br />
          <span><em>Breath</em></span
          >,<br />
          <span><em>Body</em></span
          >,<br />
          and <span><em>Mind</em></span
          >,<br />
          Illuminates<br />
          the path <br />
          to inner <br /><span class="peace">Peace and Balance.</span><br />
        </h2>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!--End Yoga Section 1-->

    <!--Begin Travel Section -->
    <section id="travel-section">
      <article class="travel-art-label">
        <div class="flex">
          <h2 class="h2-trav">What's The Best Way To Travel?</h2>
          <ul class="travel-way">
            <li class="travel-supply">
              Always carry essential documents like passports and visas.
              <img src="" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li class="travel-supply">
              Research local customs and traditions before travel
            </li>
            <li class="travel-supply">Keep an emergency contact list handy.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </article>

      <article class="travel-art-label">
        <div class="flex">
          <h2 class="h2-trav">What Do I Need To Travel With?</h2>
          <ul class="travel-with">
            <li class="travel-need">
              Supported Travel Gear with New Luggage and fresh supplies and
              everyday daily clothes for the new day
            </li>
            <li class="travel-need">
              Come prepared with emergency funds for the rainy days
            </li>
            <li class="travel-need">Passports and Visas are always forsure</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </article>

      <article class="travel-art-label">
        <div class="flex">
          <h2 class="h2-trav places">Where Should I Travel To Next?</h2>
          <ul class="list">
            <li class="travel-list">
              <span class="trav-country">Paris, France;</span>
              <p class="list-p">
                Romantic streets, iconic museums, and exquisite cuisine, an
                unforgettable story unfolds
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="travel-list">
              <span class="trav-country">Tokyo, Japan;</span>
              <p class="list-p">
                Ancient traditions meet futuristic marvels, amidst a gastronomic
                journey and a tapestry of diverse cultures, all within a city
                pulsating with vibrant energy.
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="travel-list">
              <span class="travel-country">Machu Picchu, Peru;</span>
              <p class="list-p">
                Ancient wonders amid stunning mountains, merging history,
                breathtaking landscapes, and vibrant Peruvian culture.
              </p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
    <!--End Travel Section -->
  </body>
</html>
```

An arguably more maintainable fix is to rework the non-sensical use of `position: relative` and `top/left` to instead use more sensible CSS properties to more predictably layout elements, such that there is less overlaying of elements. For example as a rough rework:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --primary-color: #33a112;
  --secondary-color: #3acabb;
  --complementary-color: #fff;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--complementary-color);
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 100px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 100;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: var(--secondary-color);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
}

.nav-link a {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 250px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-family: "Open-Sans", sans-serif;
}

.nav-link a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav-link a:hover {
  color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.nav-link a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

main#main-header {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 130px 0 200px 130px;
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: beige;
  width: 2000px;
}

.hero h1 {
  font-size: 9rem;
  color: var(--secondary-color);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.hero h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: var(--primary-color);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.hero-h1,
.hero-h3 {
  text-align: justify;
}

img.hero-img {
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
}

.hero-disc {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: "Open-Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: medium;
  color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.food1 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  width: 520px;
}

.travel2 {
  width: 600px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

.yoga1 {
  width: 600px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.hero-btn {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-family: "Open-Sans", sans-serif;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.blog-btn {
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.blog-btn:hover {
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
  color: #fff;
}

.sub-btn {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.sub-btn:hover {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
}

hr {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

section.yoga-section {
  height: 1275px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  padding: 10px 100px 10px;
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border: #000 solid 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

div.yoga-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.yoga-img {
  width: 1300px;
  margin-left: -300px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.h2-1 {
  margin-left: -700px;
  font-size: 6rem;
  color: var(--complementary-color);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
}

.h2-1 span {
  color: var(--primary-color);
  font-size: 8rem;
}

span.peace {
  color: beige;
  font-size: 8rem;
}

section#travel-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85vh;
  margin-top: -100px;
  background: linear-gradient(80deg, var(--primary-color), beige);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: gradient 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 50px;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 65%;
  }
}

article.travel-art-label {
  height: 560px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 180px;
  left: 210px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 25px 25px 20px 0;
  background-color: beige;
}

.flex {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.h2-trav {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

h2.places {
  margin-right: 125px;
}

ul li {
  width: 75%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: "Open-Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.travel-with,
.travel-way {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 22.5px;
}

.travel-need,
.travel-supply {
  margin-top: 47.5px;
}

.list {
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

li.travel-list {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: -25px;
}

.list-p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: italic;
}

section#healthy-recipes {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
}

table {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

h2#healthy-h2 {
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  left: 10px;
}

.table-head,
.table-data {
  border: 2px solid #0a0a23;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.table-head {
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 black;
}

h3#healthy-h3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: -250px;
  font-family: "open-sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin-top: -100px;
}

ol.list {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta description="design" />
    <title>Sarah's Blog</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Ubuntu:wght@700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Begin Navigation-->
    <header class="header">
      <div class="nav-logo">
        <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
      </div>

      <div class="nav-link">
        <a href="#home" class="primary">Home</a>
        <a href="#yoga" class="secondary">Yoga</a>
        <a href="#travel" class="primary">Travel</a>
        <a href="#healthy" class="secondary">Healthy Recipes</a>
        <a href="#contact" class="primary">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </header>
    <!--End Navigation-->

    <!--Begin Main-->
    <main id="main-header">
      <div class="hero">
        <h1 class="hero-h1">
          Travel,<br />
          Thrive,<br />
          Transform.
        </h1>
        <h3 class="hero-h3">
          Experience the World through Travel,<br />
          Embrace Wellness with Yoga,<br />
          Discover Health with Wholesome Recipes.
        </h3>
        <p class="hero-disc">
          Join our global community in uncovering a path to personal growth as
          <br />
          we embark on a journey to live a life of meaning and purpose together!
        </p>
        <button type="submit" value="Read The Blog" class="blog-btn hero-btn">
          Read The Blog
        </button>
        <button type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="sub-btn hero-btn">
          Subscribe
        </button>
      </div>
      <!--Begin Hero Images-->
      <div class="img-section">
        <img
          src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/KeshonsWalksOfLife/free-thinking-design-Pro.2/0fd535754c1d4f6f07fdf095defc6a4c5a1a78bc/media/food1.jpg"
          width="25%"
          title="Healthy Food Lifestyle"
          class="hero-img food1"
        />

        <div class="row">
          <img
            src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/KeshonsWalksOfLife/free-thinking-design-Pro.2/0fd535754c1d4f6f07fdf095defc6a4c5a1a78bc/media/yoga1.jpg"
            width="25%"
            title="Yoga Lifestyle"
            class="hero-img yoga1"
          />

          <img
            src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/KeshonsWalksOfLife/free-thinking-design-Pro.2/0fd535754c1d4f6f07fdf095defc6a4c5a1a78bc/media/travel2.jpg"
            width="25%"
            title="Traveling Lifestyle"
            class="hero-img travel2"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <!--End Hero Images-->
    <hr />
    <!--Begin Yoga Section -->
    <section class="yoga-section">
      <div class="yoga-container">
        <img
          src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/KeshonsWalksOfLife/free-thinking-design-Pro.2/0fd535754c1d4f6f07fdf095defc6a4c5a1a78bc/media/yoga-2.jpg"
          title="Yoga Lifestyle"
          class="yoga-img"
        />
        <h2 class="h2-1">
          Where<br />
          The union of <br />
          <span><em>Breath</em></span
          >,<br />
          <span><em>Body</em></span
          >,<br />
          and <span><em>Mind</em></span
          >,<br />
          Illuminates<br />
          the path <br />
          to inner <br /><span class="peace">Peace and Balance.</span><br />
        </h2>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!--End Yoga Section 1-->

    <!--Begin Travel Section -->
    <section id="travel-section">
      <article class="travel-art-label">
        <div class="flex">
          <h2 class="h2-trav">What's The Best Way To Travel?</h2>
          <ul class="travel-way">
            <li class="travel-supply">
              Always carry essential documents like passports and visas.
              <img src="" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li class="travel-supply">
              Research local customs and traditions before travel
            </li>
            <li class="travel-supply">Keep an emergency contact list handy.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </article>

      <article class="travel-art-label">
        <div class="flex">
          <h2 class="h2-trav">What Do I Need To Travel With?</h2>
          <ul class="travel-with">
            <li class="travel-need">
              Supported Travel Gear with New Luggage and fresh supplies and
              everyday daily clothes for the new day
            </li>
            <li class="travel-need">
              Come prepared with emergency funds for the rainy days
            </li>
            <li class="travel-need">Passports and Visas are always forsure</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </article>

      <article class="travel-art-label">
        <div class="flex">
          <h2 class="h2-trav places">Where Should I Travel To Next?</h2>
          <ul class="list">
            <li class="travel-list">
              <span class="trav-country">Paris, France;</span>
              <p class="list-p">
                Romantic streets, iconic museums, and exquisite cuisine, an
                unforgettable story unfolds
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="travel-list">
              <span class="trav-country">Tokyo, Japan;</span>
              <p class="list-p">
                Ancient traditions meet futuristic marvels, amidst a gastronomic
                journey and a tapestry of diverse cultures, all within a city
                pulsating with vibrant energy.
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="travel-list">
              <span class="travel-country">Machu Picchu, Peru;</span>
              <p class="list-p">
                Ancient wonders amid stunning mountains, merging history,
                breathtaking landscapes, and vibrant Peruvian culture.
              </p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
    <!--End Travel Section -->
  </body>
</html>
```